# How to create a object of Bigdecimal having String value in c++ code while using JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

To call a java mehod from c++ having BigDecimal parameters init. I use JNI and did below coading:

A BigDecimal is just a java object for the native part.
 So first you need to create it. Therefore you need a class and a method ID.

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/math/BigDecimal");
jmethodID = mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(D)V");
This would be the Construtor of BigDecimal taking a double.
 After this you can create two objects.
jobject bd1 = (*env)->NewObject(env,cls, mid, 1.222);
jobject bd2 = (*env)->NewObject(env,cls, mid, 0.0500);
```

here we pass double value in bd1 and bd2 . If i want to pass a string value in bd1 & bd2 e.g. in place of 1.222 i pass str where string str = "hello" . 
what changes i need to do. also how to print bd1 and bd2 value .

Answer (score 0):

Building strings using JNI is much easier than a custom class, since JNI has methods which do this for you:

```
jstring str1 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "hello world");
```

Comment: I want to pass string value in bd1 , bd2. As of now we pass double init.
e.g. in plase of jobject bd1 = (*env)->NewObject(env,cls, mid, 1.222);
i want  jobject bd1 = (*env)->NewObject(env,cls, mid, str );   where string str = "hello"
how do we implement it.

Comment: Use `atof()`? Converting a string to a float is not a difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider this. I would add a delegating Java method that takes a String, have the JNI call that, and have the delegating method do the conversion and call the target method. Don't do a jot more work in the JNI layer than you need to. It's too hard, and the delegating method is just four lines of easy Java code.